# Asignar nuevo valor dentro de un vector de objetos

Tags: java, array

Tengo un vector `vropa` al que quiero aplicar un método según la categoría, por ejemplo, aplicar descuento a todos los objetos cuya categoría sea Pantalón, el problema que tengo es que al recorrer el vector me pregunta el porcentaje a aplicar a cada instancia y lo que quiero yo es que el descuento se aplique a todos los productos cuya categoría coincida  a la indicada por consola:

```
 public cdouble getPrecioDescuento() {
     Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
     double descuento;
     System.out.print("Ingrese el porcentaje de descuento: ");
     descuento = Double.parseDouble(teclado.nextLine());

     return this.precio * (descuento / 100);

 }
    //*****************METODO DESCUENTO*************************

 public void descuentoCategoria () {

     Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
     String categoria;

     System.out.print("Ingrese la categoría para descuento: ");
     categoria = teclado.nextLine();

     for (int i = 0; i < vropa.size(); i++) {

         if(vropa.elementAt(i).getCategoria().compareTo(categoria) == 0) {
             vropa.elementAt(i).Setprecio(vropa.elementAt(i).getPrecioDescuento());
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes preguntar por la categoría en cuestión, si la categoría es la que quieres, en vez de hacer esto:

```
if(vropa.elementAt(i).getCategoria().compareTo(categoria) == 0) {
    vropa.elementAt(i).Setprecio(vropa.elementAt(i).getPrecioDescuento());
```

Puedes recoger el descuento en una variable para después recorrer tu vector `vropa` y aplicarle el descuento a cada elemento:

```
if(vropa.elementAt(i).getCategoria().compareTo(categoria) == 0) {
    double descuento = getPrecioDescuento();
}

for (int i = 0; i < vropa.size(); i++) {
    vropa.elementAt(i).Setprecio(descuento);
}
```

Comment: Buenas, no se si te he entendido bien pero getPrecioDescuento() ya me retorna el precio con el descuento aplicado, lo que quiero es que me aplique el método a todos los objetos cuya categoría introduzca el usuario, de momento con un for lo hace pero 1 a  1 aplicando getPrecioDescuento en cada iteración, lo que interesa es que si ya se que la categoria "xxxx" tiene un 50% de descuento , aplicarlo a todos las instancias, perdón si no me explico bien, gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Tu problema es que cuando la categoría sea x, le tienes que aplicar el descuento a todos los elementos, pero te pide el porcentaje por cada elemento no es asi?

Comment: exacto, mediante getPrecioDescuento aplica a cada instancia con la categoría x, preguntado uno por uno , yo lo que quiero es que aplique a todos los elementos